# Why is my onload event in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, events, onload

This snippet is supposed to load the script after the body has loaded, but this code is not displaying anything on the p-tag as it is supposed to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="myBody">
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onload Event</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBody").addEventListener("load", checkCookies);
function checkCookies() {
  var text = "This page ";
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled == true)
  {
    text = "Cookies are enabled.";
  } 
  else
  {
    text = "Cookies are not enabled.";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

unlike this below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="checkCookies()">
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onload Event</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function checkCookies() {
  var text = "";
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled == true)
  {
    text = "Cookies are enabled.";
  } 
  else
  {
    text = "Cookies are not enabled.";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried it several times, but can't fix the bug.

Comment: use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkCookies);` - not 100% sure why your code doesn't work

Comment: It worked, but it was not controlled by the <body> tag again. This is for the whole webpage, i guess?

Comment: it's not 100% the same, no - in fact, DOMContentLoaded fires BEFORE body onload

Comment: I'm curious why you think the `load` event will fire for the body *after* the script that is in the body? Doesn't your body element *before* the script can run?

Comment: ok, Thank you. Can you help get why the first code was not running please, I prefer js throughout than using it in HTML tags. @Mark

Comment: Hmm, interesting @JaromandaX. It's not happening for me. Running in Safari the event handler is never called. FWIW — I wasn't directing that comment at you, but rather the OP.

Comment: Help me correct the syntax please.

Comment: oh, sorry, @Mark ... `<body onload="xyz()"` runs after, `document.body.addEventListener("load", ...` NEVER runs - that's why I saud "body onload" - was saying that DOMCotnentLoaded isn't 100% the same as `body onload=`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Change the second parameter on your `addEventListener` to invoke the method like so:

```
document.getElementById("myBody").addEventListener("load", checkCookies());
```

`adddEventListener` expects an [Arrow Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as it's second argument.

Check out the MDN docs for `addEventListener` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback)

Comment: no, addEventListener does NOT expect an arrow function expression. This will execute checkCookies **immediately** - perhaps **YOU** should check the documentation you linked to

Comment: Interesting! I wasn't able to get it to execute at all when passing in a function variable, do you have any examples of this?

Comment: @JaromandaX checked the documentation and that's what I got from it. No need to be sassy man lol

Comment: not being sassy man - what you've posted isn't even an arrow function, it's calling a function and using the returned value as the argument to addEventListener

Comment: I'm writing what I got from the resources above and what I've tested locally. For the Arrow Function Expressions page it literally gives the `() => expression` syntax, which matches the `addEventListener` syntax for the second parameter. I ended up writing `checkCookies` as such and didn't post that, so thanks for allowing me to clear that up.

Comment: You read the resources wrong - there is no arrow notation in `.addEventListener("load", checkCookies())` (your code in your answer) - also you can use `function() { ... }` syntax, as documented on that MDN page BEFORE any mention of an arrow function

Answer (score 2):

The load event fires on the `window`. It does not exist for arbitrary elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

If you're waiting for the page to fully load including images and other media, then use the Window's load event. Otherwise use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkCookies);`

Comment: FYI (for OP) `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` fires first, then `<body onload=` and then `window.addEventListener('load'`

Comment: To be accurate, there are `load` events on other elements ...`<img>` and `<video>` and `<audio>` and `<iframe>` :p